# How to efficiently find quantile (root) of integral function

Tags: calculus, definite-integrals, algorithms, newton-raphson, quantile

Let $f(x)$ be a density function on $\mathbb R$; I want to find numerically the $\alpha$ quantile of the associated distribution, i.e. I want to find $c$ such that

$$\int_{-\infty}^c f(x)dx = \alpha$$

$f(x)$ is reasonably fast to compute, but if I apply the usual root-finding algorithms (say, newton-raphson) I would need to compute the integral of $f(x)$ at every iteration, which is impractical.

Do you have any references as of how solve the problem numerically? Is there a root-finding algorithm that doesn't need the evaluation of the function, but only of its derivative (in this case $f(x)$) ?

Comment: You should be able to compute the integral to machine precision in 30 function evaluations using exp-sinh quadrature, then use bisection->Newton to find the root. I don't see why this is impractical.

Comment: An additional idea is to use exp-sinh to evaluate $F(0)$, then $F(c)$ can be evaluated via tanh-sinh quadrature in ~10 function evaluations. Start creating a lookup table for $F(c_{i})$ as the iterations proceed. If need be, build a barycentric rational approximation to $F$.

Comment: @user14717 Hi! What is a barycentirc rational approximation? Anyhow, if I use the tanh-sinh quadrature to compute $F(c)$, I still need to call the density ~11 times per iteration. It could work though.

Comment: https://pdfs.semanticscholar.org/c6d7/db02c7f6648f0a2146d04f14f8f46a7b5a8a.pdf

Comment: An implementation of barycentric rational interpolation: https://github.com/boostorg/math/pull/58

Comment: An implementation of tanh-sinh and exp-sinh quadrature: https://github.com/boostorg/math/pull/60